# How to make Bootstrap jQuery datatable responsive and increase/decrease the scrollbar height according to the page size?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, datatables

I want to make my web application repsonsive which is using Bootstrap 2.1.1 (can't switch to latest Bootstrap due to client restrictions).

I am also using Bootstrap jQuery datatable 1.9.2.

For this purpose I used fluid components (`container-fluid`,`row-fluid`) of Bootstrap, however I found that it dynamically adjusts width according to page size/resolution of screen but height remains the same and doesn't use full height of the screen.

So I found one solution  of using resize event and setting the height dynamically.

```
$( window ).resize(function() {
   $('#abonnement_Scroll').css('height',($(window).height()-($(window).height()/100*51)))
}
```

Although this is working but only for certain resolutions. In screen resolution having height less 1000px, the height doesn't get decrease further and footer below the datatable is not able to fit in the screen.

And I also found that sScrollY property of jQuery datatable does not take value in %, hence not able to make it directly responsive.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

It will automatically provides scroll bar when you resize the window

```
<div style="overflow:auto;max-width:500px;max-height:300px">
  <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
    ...
  </table>
</div>
```

## **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jq8hdzy5/)**

Comment: hi jake745, table-resposive seems to be for bootstrap3 i am using bootstrap 2.1.1.

Comment: hi @jake745, i have added more rows to the table and now if you try to resize the browser window then you will notice the table won't adjust to its size ,and that is the same problem i am facing.             [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jq8hdzy5/3/)

Comment: I can't understant what you are trying to say. Can you explain